# JQ get data from an array of array

Tags: json, linux, jq

How can I get a value from an array of arrays. This is JSON from which I have to get the data:

```json
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "matrix",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "myMetric": "ABC"
        },
        "values": [
          [
            1633597734,
            "64.54166666666667"
          ],
          [
            1633598034,
            "65.51666666666667"  <-- wanted value
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have to get value from the last array in `values`.
I tried the following:

```
jq .data.result.values input.json
jq .data.result.values[] input.json
jq .data.result.values[][] input.json
```

For every one the result is:

```
jq: error (at json:0): Cannot index array with string "values"
```

How can I get value from the last array in `values`?

Comment: Can you try with `jq .data.result[0].values[1][1] input.json` or if you want all the quoted floating point numbers `jq .data.result[0].values[][1] input.json`?

Comment: If you want the last entry in the last array in `values` of the last entry in `result`, this would work: `.data.result[-1].values[-1][-1]`; did you want just that, or for all `values`?

Comment: @MarkoE the first one is what I need and works fine, tnx

Comment: @BenjaminW. exactly what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative index to enumerate from the back of an array: to get the last element of the last array in the `values` of the last element of `result`:

```
.data.result[-1].values[-1][-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

demo: https://jqplay.org/s/YMpB8-A4-Q

```
filter: 
.data.result[].values[1][1]?

input:
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "matrix",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "myMetric": "ABC"
        },
        "values": [
          [
            1633597734,
            "64.54166666666667"
          ],
          [
            1633598034,
            "65.51666666666667"
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

output:
"65.51666666666667"
```